# virtual hosts map to directory structure

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have read the mass virtual host help on apache but as a relative newbie I am left a little confused. I know my problem must be acheiveable as it is a pretty basic problem but i am lost...

Basically I have lots of virtual hosts pointing to my server and the file structure that they point to for their DocumentRoot is consistent... e.g..

```
www.mydomain.com -> /home/blah/vhosts/mydomain.com/www/public
abc.mydomain.com -> /home/blah/vhosts/mydomain.com/abc/public

www.another.co.uk -> /home/blah/vhosts/another.co.uk/www/public
def.another.co.uk -> /home/blah/vhosts/another.co.uk/def/public
```

If possible, I also need to redirect non-www.* to www.* but taking into account the possibility of a subdomain, so that:

- `mydomain.com` is redirected to `www.mydomain.com`
- `abc.mydomain.com` is **NOT** redirected to `www.mydomain.com` as it is
  handled with the definition above (due to directory structure)

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here what I do for all my vhosts: I'm using [Apache writemap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap).

Create a new "partner.txt" file with partners like this:

```
0 www
1 partner1
2 partner2
3 partner1
```

Then compile it, and add use it into your rewriterules to find out whether the prefix is a partner or not, like this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.fr
    DocumentRoot "/web/htdocs/olivier/mydomain.fr/dev/website"
    ServerName mydomain.fr
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.fr
    ErrorLog "/web/logs/mydomain.error.log"
    CustomLog "|/opt/httpd/bin/rotatelogs /web/logs/mydomain.fr/access_log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S.log 5M" combined
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

    RewriteEngine On
    # trying to hack = redirect:
    RewriteRule (.*)setup.php http://disneyland.fr/ [NC,R,L]
    RewriteRule (.*)admin(.*) http://disneyland.fr/ [NC,R,L]

    # if your host doesn't begin with "www" add it and redirect:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.(fr|com|net|org|eu) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.%1$1 [QSA,R=301,L]

    RewriteMap partners \
      dbm:/web/htdocs/olivier/mydomain.fr/rewriterules/partners.map

    # test if known partner:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.)mydomain.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=PARTNER:${templates:%1|notfound}]

    # if partner not found or empty, 404:
    RewriteCond %{ENV:PARTNER} ^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:PARTNER} notfound
    RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This may be a part of the solution (+1) but it's maybe too much your solution and not the solution to his problem. For example he needs to handle several different domains. So this may need further explanations. For example what is the effect of setting the PARTNER env variable in the matching rewrite?

Comment: Hey you're right man I've make a mistake in my answer, corrected... Then the explanation: The effect of setting the PARTNER env variable in the matching rewrite helps you to know whether to prefix is valid. I.E. if you have partner1, partner2 and partner3 and someone types "partner47.mydomain.com" then you will know partner47 isn't a partner because `PARTNER` will have the default value = 'notfound' => the last rewriterule will do a 404 for unknow partners. We could have made a redirect to `www.mydomain.com` though